# Avoiding the pitfalls of Python-style slicing

Tags: c++, python, slice

As a side project and C++11 practice I am working on a small library of n-dimensional arrays in the vein of Numpy. I intend to mostly follow Numpy conventions but in the case of slicing I'm thinking about opting for something different.

The issue is that the last elements of ranges are always inaccessible when using a negative variable for indexing, and also when iterating backwards. For example, `array[x:y]` cannot include the last element with negative `y`. EDIT: I was unaware that passing `None` solves precisely this issue in Python. The question though still stands as it seems to be the kind of ad-hoc solution that I'd like to avoid, and the counterpart of it in C++ would be cumbersome.

I've considered three main options:

1. Use inclusive ranges, like in Haskell. After all, Haskellers aren't particularly bothered by it. This is though a significant deviation from Python experience.
2. Disallow negative indexing. It is not that much of an improvement in usability, and a simple subtraction from the size suffices when counting indices from the end is absolutely needed.
3. Slice the same way as in Python. The mentioned issue comes up rarely in real code and people can identify and circumvent it easily when it does come up.

I'm currently leaning towards option one. Any opinions on the matter?

Comment: How is the negative-index issue related to the issue of including/excluding the endpoint?

Comment: This may get flagged as subjective.

Comment: "the last elements of ranges are always inaccessible" - are you stating this as a requirement for your code? Python slicing doesn't have such a silly restriction.

Comment: I advise following the conventions of the language you are targeting.  Otherwise you'll just annoy your users.

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken in saying "last elements of ranges are always inaccessible when using a variable for indexing."

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 100
>>> r = list(range(10))
>>> r[x:y]      # much larger number than last index
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> r[x:len(r)] # length of the list
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> y = None
>>> r[x:y]      # variable set to None
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

`None` holds for when reading the list backwards as well.

Comment: Please excuse me for the unclear formulation, I edited the question. I was also unaware of the "None" trick.